# Traveling between Terminals 1 and 2 at CDG

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cdg, airport-terminals

I will be arriving into Terminal 2 of CDG (Paris), while my other family members will be arriving into Terminal 1 a few hours later.

Is it possible to meet them at Terminal 1 and go through customs with them, or would I have to go through customs at the terminal in which I arrived?

Similarly, my family and I will be departing from different terminals of CDG; would it be possible for them to come and have dinner at Terminal 2 before heading to their departure terminal (Terminal 1)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot join them at terminal 1, because the airside shuttle buses connecting the terminals can only be used by holders of an onward Boarding pass

You will Need to clear immigration separately